# Get multiple results for multiple inputs in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a score table for upcoming NFL season so a friend and I can fill out our weekly scores and the sheet will show who is the winner at the end of the season. We are playing in different fantasy leagues so we will decide who is the winner by comparing points every week and have the winning player get 1 point for each week he came out on top. We decided to play untill the end of the 13th week to get an uneven amount of weeks.

I already have a system that will count the amount of weekly wins per player and the output of that number is posted in two cells. H3 shows the amount of times player 1 has won, H4 shows the amount of times player 2 has won. I would now like to have H5 show the winner but ONLY after it is decided that the other player can't win anymore.

All I have now in H5 is a simple statement which looks if player 1 has more points than player 2. If that is true it will display the name of player 1, if it is untrue it will display the name of player 2;

=IF(H3>H4;"player1";"player2")

The main problem is that as long as player 1 isn't winning the result will ALWAYS be untrue (and thus it will always display the name of player 2). Even when the score is 0-0 or even 4-4. So I think it would be wise to put in another condition where it only displays if one of the players has more than 7 points (as it would be impossible for the other player to win anymore).

So to summarise:
How do I keep cell H5 empty if it is not decided who has won.
How do I add the condition that one of the players must have >7 points before the winner is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check first if one of them is greater 7 and if yes then use your formula else return an empty string

```
=IF(OR(H3>=7;H4>=7);IF(H3>H4;"player1";"player2");"")
```

Comment: That OR statement did the trick, I think I was all hung up on IF / AND constructions. Also I was thinking the other way around making it much more complicated than nessecary. Thanks alot!